# Why is checking for a variables existence taking more time than copying an array which should be a O(1) vs O(n) operation?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, big-o, profiling

These numbers don't make sense to me.
Why does checking for list existence or checking len() of an list take longer than an copy()?
It's O(1) vs O(n) operations.

```
Total time: 3.01392 s
File: all_combinations.py
Function: recurse at line 15

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    15                                               @profile
    16                                               def recurse(in_arr, result=[]):
    17                                                   nonlocal  count
    18                                           
    19   1048576     311204.0      0.3     10.3          if not in_arr:
    20    524288     141102.0      0.3      4.7              return
    21                                           
    22    524288     193554.0      0.4      6.4          in_arr = in_arr.copy() # Note: this adds a O(n) operation
    23                                           
    24   1572863     619102.0      0.4     20.5          for i in range(len(in_arr)):
    25   1048575     541166.0      0.5     18.0              next = result + [in_arr.pop(0)]
    26   1048575     854453.0      0.8     28.4              recurse(in_arr, next)
    27   1048575     353342.0      0.3     11.7              count += 1
```

```
Total time: 2.84882 s
File: all_combinations.py
Function: recurse at line 38

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    38                                               @profile
    39                                               def recurse(result=[], index=0):
    40                                                   nonlocal count
    41                                                   nonlocal in_arr
    42                                           
    43                                                   # base
    44   1048576     374126.0      0.4     13.1          if index > len(in_arr):
    45                                                       return
    46                                           
    47                                                   # recur
    48   2097151     846711.0      0.4     29.7          for i in range(index, len(in_arr)):
    49   1048575     454619.0      0.4     16.0              next_result = result + [in_arr[i]]
    50   1048575     838434.0      0.8     29.4              recurse(next_result, i + 1)
    51   1048575     334930.0      0.3     11.8              count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that making the copy takes longer by itself than the O(1) operations you mentioned.

But remember that your base case is running far more often than the recursive case.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I imagine that gap would grow as N increases to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you reference with "it" in your question.  The generic ("royal") "it" does *not* take longer; your *implementation* is what takes longer.  In most language implementations, `len` is **O(1)**, because it's an instance attribute maintained along with any changes in the object.  This existence implementation is slower because it recurs instead of simply iterating through the list, although it's still **O(N)**.